# Taking in multiple different objects and displaying their methods java

Tags: java

[Given code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jP4xg.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zbC7.png)

Write a static method printSleep() that takes an array of objects of type Human, Dog and Cat as the parameter. The method iterates through the array and for each array element, the method prints "Humans sleep  8 hours" on a single line if the object type is Human; if the object type is Dog, the method prints "Dogs sleep 14 hours" on a single line, and if the object type is Cat, the method prints "Cats sleeps 16 hours" on a single line. My current answer:

public static void printSleep(Sleep[] s){

```
Sleep[] a = new Sleep[3];

s[0] = new Cat();
s[1] = new Dog();
s[2] = new Human();

for(Sleep obj : a) {
    obj.sleep();
}
```

}

My code is printing nothing. Can someone offer me some tips? Thanks in advance

Comment: "I'm getting errors" ... and the errors are?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not post text (code, results) as images, see [why not use images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Main.java:25: error: method printSleep in class Main cannot be applied to given types;
printSleep(s);;

Comment: You don't actually print anything anywhere. Shouldn't 'printSleep' take an agument? eg. `public static void printSleep(Sleep[] s){` Then you would iterate through and print the results of the sleep method.

Comment: Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Sleep obj : s) {
obj.sleep();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you initializing the class in method just do it in `main` and pass it `printSleep` method

```
public static void main(String args[]){

        Sleep[] a = new Sleep[3];

        a[0] = new Cat();
        a[1] = new Dog();
        a[2] = new Human();
        printSleep(a);


    }

    public static void printSleep(Sleep[] s){

        for(Sleep obj : s) {
            obj.sleep();
        }
    }
```